# How should I create test cases for things that should not be present?

Tags: test-design, testcase, test-creation

How should I create a test case, or what should the test case be, when the scenario is for a function that shouldn't be in the system?

I'm creating test cases based on the FSD (Functional Specification Document). Our FSD is composed of Requirements, Processes, and Fields for specific modules. While executing my test case, I have encountered a button that isn't in the FSD. How should I create a test case for this?

I am thinking of something like "System must not have buttons that aren't stated in the FSD" but that seems wrong.

I'm kind of new in QA, and in our company, we have a standard to use the word "System must, System must not, User must, or User must not" in all of our test cases.

Comment: Related: [Whitelist Testing vs. Blacklist Testing](https://medium.com/@roesslerj/whitelist-testing-vs-blacklist-testing-cac5b9435aa1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test case seems fine, if that is truly the requirement.  Before going further, I would check with the Product Manager or someone if that functionality is intended (and just not documented in the FSD).

If the FSD is truly "the bible", I would phrase the test case "System must not expose functionality that is not documented in the FSD", but this is just a wording preference on my part.

Comment: thank you for the asnwer or kind of advise. For us, we strictly based on the FSD it's our kind of ACE when arguing with the Dev team.